# gwt application doesn't start after nocache.js loads

Tags: java, gwt

we have a GWT application running fine in production environment, but we're noticing a strange behaviour in some rare, random cases.

The problem is that our home page (the GWT entry point) is stuck with a loading message.

Looking throw the generated network traffic, from the login attempt, to the loading message, we can see that the *.nocache.js is correctly loaded from the server (http 200) but the js file declared inside the *.gwt.xml file are not loaded (no server request at all).

It seems that the nocache.js file is loaded correctly, but not executed, thus the absence of the server requests.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.